# Can I imply something by omitting two operands of an 'or-operation'?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

I've got a question about the use of implications during the process of proving something. I will get more specific. I tried to solve the following problem:

[image]

The solution is straight forward. Show that L satisfies all axioms of a poset under the given conditions. I've got stuck proving that $a \le b \wedge b\le c \implies a \le c$.

Here's my attempt to present a solution.

$a \le b \wedge b\le c$

$\iff (\ a = b \vee a < b)\ \wedge (\ b = c \vee b < c)\ $

$\iff [\ (\ a = b \vee a < b)\ \wedge (\ b = c )\ ]\ \vee [\ (\ a = b \vee a < b)\ \wedge (\ b < c )\ ]\ $

$\iff \langle  [\ (\ a = b )\ \wedge (\ b=c)\ ]\ \vee [\ (\ a < b )\ \wedge (\ b = c )\ ]\ \rangle \vee \langle [\ (\ a = b)\ \wedge (\ b < c )\ ]\ \vee [\ (\ a < c)\ \wedge (b < c) ]\ \rangle $

$\iff [\ (\ a = b )\ \wedge (\ b=c)\ ]\ \vee [\ (\ a < c)\ \wedge (b < c) ] \vee [\ (\ a < b )\ \wedge (\ b = c )\ ]\ \vee [\ (\ a = b)\ \wedge (\ b < c )\ ]\ \ $

$\implies [\ (\ a = b )\ \wedge (\ b=c)\ ]\ \vee [\ (\ a < c)\ \wedge (b < c) ]  \implies (a = c) \wedge (a<c) \implies a \le c$

Now, while this seems to lead to a correct solution, I am very unsure about the first implication I've made by omitting two of the []'s. Can somebody tell meif this is correct? And if not, what would be the correct formal proof?

Comment: Feel free to edit my question title. I wasn't sure how I should phrase it.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use words in your proof?

Comment: @David This textbook didn't say explicitly say that I couldn't use them. But it doesn't matter really. The real question is, if it is correct or not to make such an implication as I did.

Comment: I don't agree that it doesn't matter.  One of the essential things about a proof is to communicate an argument to someone else.  A clearly written proof with words is, nearly always, way more comprehensible than a wordless string of symbols.  If you frame your proof this way: "Let $a\le b$ and $b\le c$.  Case I: $a=b$... Case II: $b=c$... Case III: neither of the above..." then I think you will find it very easy to complete the proof by filling in the dots, **and moreover**, answering your original question, very easy to be sure that your logic is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your next-to-last line reads:
$$[(a=b) \wedge (b=c) ] \vee [(a<c) \wedge (b<c)] \vee [(a<b) \wedge (b=c)] \vee [(a=b) \wedge (b<c)] \enspace.$$

What is left is to show that all four disjuncts imply $a \leq c$.

- $[(a=b) \wedge (b=c)]$ implies $a=c$ by transitivity of equality; $a=c$, in turn, implies $a \leq c$.
- $[(a<c) \wedge (b<c)]$ implies $a<c$ by transitivity of $<$;  $a<c$, in turn, implies $a \leq c$.
- $[(a<b) \wedge (b=c)]$ also implies $a<c$, hence $a \leq c$.
- $[(a=b) \wedge (b<c)]$ also implies $a<c$, hence $a \leq c$.

As to the question whether you can omit two disjuncts, the answer, if I understand the question, is no.  You cannot focus on the cases that support the conclusion you are trying to prove and ignore the others.

Comment: Believe it or not, I was actually able to prove reflexivity and antisymmetry on my own. I got stuck at the transitivity property.

Comment: Believe it or not, I was fully convinced I had read the statement of antisymmetry.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that $[\ (\ a \implies d )\ \wedge (\ b \implies d )\ ]\ \iff [\ (\ a \vee b )\ \implies d ]\ $ holds.